# How to get DbSet object for any table with table's name as string from DbContext in C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

How to get `DbSet` object for any table with table's name as string from `DbContext` in C# using reflection
like:-

```
public DbSet GetTableObject(string tableName){

//TODO

}
```

This function should return the `DbSet` object for given table name using reflection in C# with `DbContext`.
How can we do that?

Comment: Do you want to use the Table name in the underlying database, or the Entity Name?

Can you guarantee that the table name is configured using a TableAttribute?

What version of EF?

Comment: Why do you need this? Can't you use the `DbContext.Set<T>()` method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you need this, but I guess you are looking for something like this?

```
 public object GetTableObject(string tableName)
        {

            PropertyInfo[] properties = typeof(Datalayer.Model.MyContext).GetProperties();
            var prop = properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == tableName);

            using (var db = new Datalayer.Model.MyContext())
            {
                var table = prop?.GetValue(db);
                return table;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This will only match if the property name is the same as the table name.

Comment: Thanks, I can get the values of table fetched using table name as string, but I want to perform CRUD operations like insert, update, delete entity using entity we just fetched using table name as string.